# what is the best way to design mysql tables which has relation to each other?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Mysql tables which is bellow :

**users :**

```
uid    uname    pass   email    st_id
================================================
1      xxx      xx     xx       1, 2,3, 4
```

**station :**

```
st_id  st_name
================
1      xxx    
2      xxx    
3      xxx    
4      xxx
```

When I added a new user I need to select multiple station**s** and I am inserting the `st_id` as comma (,) separated value to `users`  table.

Is it better to insert `st_id` in this way ?

**OR**

I can insert each different `st_id` to `users` table then in `users` table total row will be 4. Like bellow :

**users :**

```
uid    uname    pass   email    st_id
================================================
1      xxx      xx     xx       1
1      xxx      xx     xx       2
1      xxx      xx     xx       3
1      xxx      xx     xx       4
```

But this way it will be too many redundant data!

Which database table design is best and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a third table!

```
create table UserStations (
    UserStationId int auto_increment,
    UserId int not null,
    StationId int not null,
    primary key (UserStationId),
    unique (UserId, StationId),  -- probably intended
    constraint fk_userstations_user foreign key (UserId) references users(uid),
    constraint fk_userstatsion_station foreign key (StationId) references stations(st_id)
);
```

This is called a *junction* table.  It is the right way to represent a many-to-many relationship in a relational database.

The wrong way is using a delimited list of ids.  Why?

- Values should be stored using appropriate types.  You are storing numbers as integers.
- A column should contain a single value, not a list.
- A foreign key relationship should be explicitly declared.
- SQL does not have strong support for string types.
- Queries on the fields cannot take advantage of indexes.
- Uniqueness is hard to maintain with a list of values in a string.

Comment: Yea, that's a great answer.